# Python Requests module behaving different in a for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a script which reads a line (URL) in a text file, checks its `code_status` and then print to the user, however, when using for loop it gives wrong `code_status` while testing with one URL in the `request.get(url)` gives the right one.

> Problematic code

```
import requests
with open('test2.txt', 'r+') as arquivo:
        for linhas in arquivo:
                url = requests.get(linhas)
                print url.status_code
```

> Achieves the right code.

```
import requests         
url = requests.get(URL)
print url.status_code
```

You guys can test both the txt file and single URL with the following URL: https://api.github.com/user

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: github url is wrong, can you fix it please?

Comment: Possibly the text file has a newline character at the end and the URL is thus wrong.

Comment: @KamyarGhasemlou There's nothing wrong with url o.O.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida I've noticed that when the urls are printed in the terminal but the text file are well orderly

Comment: @Milbol when you read from file lin-by-line, you end up with a new line at the end of each entry, you ahve to strip it. see my answer for the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your problem is because of the `\n` character at the end of each line.
this should fix it:

```
import requests
with open('test2.txt', 'r+') as arquivo:
        for linhas in arquivo:
                url = requests.get(linhas.strip())
                print url.status_code
```